# How to combine/group total of two properties

Tags: powershell

I've played around with group objects with a few variations with no luck.

How would I go about summing the total row count by each directory?

```
Rowcount Directory                  
-------- ---------                  
      23 Collateral        
     289 Collateral        
      14 Collateral        
      63 Collateral        
      21 Credit            
     398 CreditValuation   
     101 CreditValuation   
     116 CreditValuation   
      36 EmirCollateral    
       3 EmirFx            
      35 EmirFXValuation   
      18 EmirRates         
      20 EmirRates         
     397 EmirRatesValuation
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to *group* your records based on the `Directory` property. Then you can calculate the sum using the `Measure-Object` cmdlet. Here is an example:

```
$sample | Group-Object Directory | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Directory = $_.Group.Directory[0]
        Rowcount  = ($_.Group.Rowcount | Measure-Object -sum).Sum
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. 

Worked a treat. Appreciated.